# use of the ampersand here means pre_match?

Tags: ruby, regex

What is the ampersand doing in the code below?

```
s.reverse.gsub( /\d{3}(?=\d)/, '\&,' ).reverse
```

One would think, after attempting to look up such things, that it is a special variable meaning post_match or pre_match, but the docs say nothing about ampersands - only dollar signs either followed by or preceded by a tick mark.

Comment: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Special+global+variables

Comment: so there it is! I was over on http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/MatchData.html - Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\&` defines the whole string that is matched by the regex. see this simplified example:

```
s = "p1:1 1:1";
print s.gsub( /[a-z]/, '[\&],' ) ## only p is matched
```

output: `[p],1:1 1:1`

Similarly, the `\1` defines the first group that is matched from the regex. (Similar goes for \2,\3... so on). An example:

```
s = "p1:1 1:1";
print s.gsub( /(\d:\d)/, '[\1]' )
```

output: `p[1:1] [1:1]`

Comment: so the parentheses in my example are non capturing... and the ampersand is for when you only need one real capture group and you don't feel like putting parentheses around them...?

Comment: so this is the exact equivalent, right?   s.reverse.gsub( /(\d{3})(?=\d)/, '\1,' ).reverse